# Regular Expression to split double and integer numbers in a string

Tags: java, regex, split, floating-point, integer

i need a regular expression to separate integer and double elements of a string, like the example below:

```
String input = "We have the number 10 and 10.3, and i want to split both";
String[] splitted = input.split(/*REGULAR EXPRESSION*/);
for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i++)
    System.out.println("[" + i + "]" + " -> \"" + splitted[i] + "\"");
```

And the output will be:

- [0] -> "We have the number "
- [1] -> "10"
- [2] -> " and "
- [3] -> "10.3"
- [4] -> ", and i want to split both"

Can someone help me? I will be grateful.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: if you split at numbers you will loose them. the regex would be simply `\\d` but output is without numbers then. maybe a more complex regex helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *match* these chunks with:

```
\D+|\d*\.?\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QYfDtB/1)

**Details**:

- `\D+` - 1 or more chars other than digits
- `|` - or
- `\d*\.?\d+` - a simple integer or float (might be enhanced to `[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`, see [source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html))

A [Java demo](http://ideone.com/aUFuwZ):

```
String s = "We have the number 10 and 10.3, and i want to split both";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D+|\\d*\\.?\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    res.add(matcher.group(0)); 
} 
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: better change output so its clearer that its splitted correctly

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Well, here is [another demo link](http://ideone.com/E1wR8z).

Comment: Well, I guess I figured out a pattern for negative float/integer values: [`(?:[^\d.+-]|[-+](?!\.?\d)|[.](?!\d))+|[-+]?\d*[.]?\d+(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/QYfDtB/3). If anyone finds it helpful, I will add to the answer with explanation.